# How does correct gamma color on external screen? Linux laptop

Tags: linux, display, laptop

I have got a laptop and i would like to correct gamma color on my **external** screen.

My system: *Laptop, VGA port, Linux, Ubuntu.*

In option System->Preferences->Monitor i turn off my laptop's screen.

But bash-command  `xgamma -gamma 5` does not any effect. BTW on laptop is (if it will turn on) too.

**How can i get it?**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `xrandr` utility to change the gamma settings on external displays.

Here is how it works:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --gamma 1.5:1.5:1.5
```

Replace 1.5 with other values and see what works for you.

Also, to get the correct identifier for your external display (VGA-0 in my case) you can run

```
xrandr -q
```

to get a listing of all displays recognized in your system.